# Uncaught TypeError in fswit.js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

When I ran my index.html file in chrome it gave me an error in the fswit.js file saying that Uncaught TypeError: Undefined is not a function on the starting line of the following code

```
$(window).on('load', function (){
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
        'selectedText': 'cat'
    });
});
```

below is the fswit.js code can anyone please tell me how to remove this error ?

```
(function($)
{
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.styleswitch').click(function()
        {
            switchStylestyle(this.getAttribute("rel"));
            return false;
        });
        var c = readCookie('style');
        if (c) switchStylestyle(c);
    });

    function switchStylestyle(styleName)
    {
        $('link[rel*=style][title]').each(function(i) 
        {
            this.disabled = true;
            if (this.getAttribute('title') == styleName) this.disabled = false;
        });
        createCookie('style', styleName, 365);
    }
})(jQuery);

// Cookie functions
function createCookie(name,value,days)
{
    if (days)
    {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}
function readCookie(name)
{
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++)
    {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}
function eraseCookie(name)
{
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}

// Switcher
    jQuery('.demo_changer .demo-icon').click(function(){

        if(jQuery('.demo_changer').hasClass("active")){
            jQuery('.demo_changer').animate({"left":"-230px"},function(){
                jQuery('.demo_changer').toggleClass("active");
            });                     
        }else{
            jQuery('.demo_changer').animate({"left":"0px"},function(){
                jQuery('.demo_changer').toggleClass("active");
            });         
        } 
    });

    // Selector 

$(window).on('load', function (){
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
        'selectedText': 'cat'
    });
});

    jQuery('.demo_changer .stBgs a').click(function(){
        var bgBgCol = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        jQuery('.demo_changer .stBgs a').removeClass('current');
        jQuery('body').css({backgroundColor:'#ffffff'});
        jQuery(this).addClass('current');
        jQuery('body').css({backgroundImage:'url(' + bgBgCol + ')'});
        if (jQuery(this).hasClass('bg_t')){
            jQuery('body').css({backgroundRepeat:'repeat', backgroundPosition:'50% 0', backgroundAttachment:'scroll'});
        } else {
            jQuery('body').css({backgroundRepeat:'repeat', backgroundPosition:'50% 0', backgroundAttachment:'scroll'});
        }
        return false;
    });
```

the chrome console shows the error like this

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
fswit.js:69 (anonymous function)
jquery.js:3 n.event.dispatch
jquery.js:3 n.event.add.r.handle
```

Comment: Are you correctly including jQuery *prior* to your code?

Comment: i just updated my question. The last four lines show how it is displaying the error